# Converting binary to decimal goes wrong in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I made this program that passes a binary number into a function and prints the decimal value of that binary number. The problem is that if the binary number gets big(like 11 numbers), the function prints something completely different. I tried to solved for a couple of hours now but nothing worked.

So my question is: how can I change my program so that it prints the right decimal number even when the binary number gets big?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int int_log2_64(uint64_t x) { return 63 ^ __builtin_clzll(x); }
#define K(T) (((sizeof(#T) - 1) << 32) - T)
int digit_count(uint32_t x)
{

    static uint64_t table[] = {
        K(0), K(0), K(0),
        K(10), K(10), K(10),                         // 64
        K(100), K(100), K(100),                      // 512
        K(1000), K(1000), K(1000),                   // 4096
        K(10000), K(10000), K(10000),                // 32k
        K(100000), K(100000), K(100000),             // 256k
        K(1000000), K(1000000), K(1000000),          // 2048k
        K(10000000), K(10000000), K(10000000),       // 16M
        K(100000000), K(100000000), K(100000000),    // 128M
        K(1000000000), K(1000000000), K(1000000000), // 1024M
        K(1000000000), K(1000000000)                 // 4B
    };

    int lg2 = int_log2_64(x);

    uint64_t n = (uint64_t)(x) + table[lg2];

    return n >> 32;
}

void binaryToDecimal(long long int bin)
{
    int l = digit_count(bin);
    char str[l];
    itoa(bin, str, 10);
    float sum[l];
    int x = l - 1;
    float answer;

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '1')
        {
            sum[i] = pow(2, x);
        }
        x--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        answer = answer + sum[i];
    }
    printf("%.0f", answer);
}

int main()
{
    long long int bin = 10101101101;
    binaryToDecimal(bin);
}
```

P.S. I changed to code to this and it works

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void binaryToDecimal(char *bin)
{
    int l = strlen(bin);
    int x = l - 1;
    float sum[l];
    float answer = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (bin[i] == '1')
            answer += pow(2, x);
        else
            sum[i] = 0;
        x--;
    }

    printf("%.0f", answer);
}

int main()
{
    binaryToDecimal("010101101101");
}
```

Comment: You want `binaryToDecimal(100)` to return `4`? Do you realize the greatest `int` you can represent in 64 bits is `18446744073709551615` (`9223372036854775807` if signed)?

Comment: Also [`itoa()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) (not in the Standard, not in POSIX) takes an `int` for the first argument. You're using a `long long int` which gets converted with, possibly, a warning. Turn on all your compiler warnings. **Mind the warnings**.

Comment: Maximum unsigned 32-bit integer is `4294967295` and signed 32-bit integer is `2147483647`.

Comment: In addition to all the problems using `itoa` and using `float`, `char str[l]` is too short as it has no room for a null terminator (and no room for a possible minus sign resulting from arithmetic overflow when converting `long long int` to `int`). Also, `answer` has not been initialized.

Comment: @hasan `void binaryToDecimal(long long int bin)`. The input argument should be a string rather than `long long int`

Comment: "I made this program that passes a binary number into a function" No, it passes a _string_ looking like a binary number. It's a big difference, since there are no "decimal" or "hex" numbers in a raw C program, everything is binary. Decimal and hex are just convenient formats for users or for programmers typing the source.

Comment: One more improvement would be to eliminate the call to `pow`, which is both expensive and inaccurate.  Simply multiplying successively by 2 will get you there.  (Also, I have edited your question to restore your original code, as the question and answer don't make sense without it.)

Comment: @Lundin look now, with the original code restored.

Comment: @SteveSummit Will do, thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change my program so that it prints the right decimal number even when the binary number gets big?

By making your `bin` variable a *string*.

That is, you want

```
void binaryToDecimal(const char *str)
{
   ...
}
```

and then you can call things like

```
binaryToDecimal("101111000110000101001110");
```

When doing base conversions, I believe it is always a mistake to use an integer variable for the input.  If I say

```
int x = 12;
```

it is *not* true that "`x` is a decimal integer".  `x` is an integer, period — I just happened to use a decimal constant to get a value into it.  Or if I say

```
int y = 0x7b;
```

then it's not meaningful to say that `y` is hexadecimal — again, `y` is just an integer.

The base in which an integer is represented only matters:

- on input, when we read a number from the user using `scanf` with the `%d`, `%o`, or `%x` formats
- when converting a string with the standard library `atoi` or `strtol` functions
- on output, when we print a number using `printf` with the `%d`, `%o`, or `%x` formats

But in all of those cases, the representation where the base matters is a string of digit characters, not an integer.

There are two reasons not to write a "binary to ..." function that accepts an integer.  One is that, as you've seen, it artificially and unnecessarily limits the range of the numbers you can convert.  But the even bigger reason is that confuses the heck out of your readers, because it's just *wrong*.  If I see a function call

```
f(1001)
```

I think to myself, "Okay, the constant value one thousand and one is being passed to function `f`."  There is no circumstance under which I would imagine that it was actually trying to pass the binary number nine.

Comment: for beginner human programmer it is "decimal" (which at this stage is synonymous of "number"). the understanding will come with time

Comment: Thank you, I changed my code to just a couple of lines and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is extremely overcomplicated. Never use floats to do integer calculations.

```
unsigned binaryToDecimal(long long int bin)
{
    unsigned answer = 0;
    int shift = 0;
    while(bin)
    {
        answer += (bin % 10) << shift++;
        bin /= 10;
    }
    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    long long int bin = 10101101101;
    printf("%u\n", binaryToDecimal(bin));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5E8Gv6oqf

Or use strings to pass the binary number :

```
unsigned binaryToDecimal(char *str)
{
    unsigned answer = 0;
    while(*str)
    {
        answer <<= 1;
        answer += *str++ == '1';
    }
    return answer;
}

int main()
{ 
    printf("%u\n", binaryToDecimal("10101101101"));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4vfnETY1f